# How to do static linking in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, visual-studio, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to statically link to a third party C library in C++.

I managed to do this in Visual Studio just by specifying the .lib file in the linker input options. However, when I do the equivalent in CDT (Project Properties -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries) I get endless amounts of "undefined reference to..." errors when I try to build.

Is there anything else that I need to do to achieve static linking in CDT?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Do you want to link against a library that is result of another project in your workspace, or a library provided by your MinGW environment?

Comment: I'm not sure but that could be because your library is compiled using VC++. You probably need the binaries compiled by MinGW.

Comment: Neither, it is a third party library. I have a .lib file for static linking and another .lib and .dll for dynamic linking. I can do the dynamic linking in Eclipse, just not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that third party library is build for Visual C environment and with the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, you might be unable to link it with the MinGW compilers.

However, you can configure Eclipse CDT on Windows to compile your code with the Visual Studio command line compiler CL.EXE and then things should work as you expected.

It heavily depends on which version of Eclipse CDT you are using, because the Microsoft compiler settings plug-in is only part of the newer versions (I think its from Helios on).

Comment: I suspect this was the problem but moving over to the Visual Studio compiler wasn't feasible for us so we have settled for dynamic linking which is working for us.